# php save 0000-00-00 date to mysql when ajax sends the real date

Tags: jquery

hi i am sending a form value through $.ajax method its sending the proper date but my php script storing it as 0000-00-00. even i echo my sql query and tested in php my admin but storing 0000-00-00

here is my Jquery

```
 // saving purpose

    $(document).on('click','#btn-add',function(){
            $('#save-from').modal({show:true});
            $(document).on('click','#add-save',function(){
                var amc_id = $('#amc_id').val();
                var amc_type = $('#amc_type').val();
                var amc_start_date = $('#amc_start_date').val();
                var amc_end_date = $('#amc_end_date').val();
                var renual_date = $('#renual_date').val();
                var renual_ammount = $('#renual_ammount').val();
                var client_id = $('#client_id').val();
                var machine_id = $('#machine_id').val();
                if(amc_type === ""){
                    $('#amc_type').focus();
                    $('#amc_type').val('Enter enter amc tyoe');
                    return;
                }
                $.ajax({

                    url:"include/insert-amc-class.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{'amc_id':amc_id, 'amc_type':amc_type, 'amc_start_date':amc_start_date, 'amc_end_date':amc_end_date, 'renual_date':renual_date,'renual_ammount':renual_ammount,'client_id':client_id,'machine_id':machine_id},
                    dataType:"text",

                    success:function(html){
                        $('#save-from').modal('hide');
                        $('#modal-success').modal({show:true});
                    }
                });
            });
    });// end of save
```

and here is my php script

```
    <?php
include_once "db_config.php";

class AMC{
    public $db;
        public function __construct(){
            $this->db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {         
                echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";        
            exit;     
            }
        }
    // to save amc details to database, to be called into amc-page.php      
        public function insertAmc($amc_id,$amc_type,$amc_start_date,$amc_end_date,$renual_date,$renual_ammount,$client_id,$machine_id){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `amc`(`amc_id`, `amc_type`, `amc_start_date`, `amc_end_date`, `renual_date`, `renual_ammount`, `client_id`, `machine_id`) VALUES   ('$amc_id','$amc_type','$amc_start_date','$amc_end_date','$renual_date','$renual_ammount','$client_id','$machine_id')";  
            $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql);
            echo $sql;
            return $result;
        }                   
    }

$amc = new AMC();       
$amc_id = $_POST['amc_id'];

$amc_type = $_POST['amc_type'];    
$amc_start_date= $_POST['amc_start_date'];

$amc_end_date = $_POST['amc_end_date'];    
$renual_date = $_POST['renual_date'];
$renual_ammount = $_POST['renual_ammount'];

$client_id = $_POST['client_id'];
$machine_id = $_POST['machine_id'];    
$amc->insertAmc($amc_id,$amc_type,$amc_start_date,$amc_end_date,$renual_date,$renual_ammount,$client_id,$machine_id);
?>
```

this the sql Query when i echo it

```
INSERT INTO `amc`(`amc_id`, `amc_type`, `amc_start_date`, `amc_end_date`, `renual_date`, `renual_ammount`, `client_id`, `machine_id`) VALUES   ('7','4c','31-08-2016','27-01-2017','','70000','1','1')
```

Comment: Use prepared Statements, to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: sure sir.. but for now i need help with that.

Comment: what is the locale in your db

Comment: i am using in my local server. i have no idea about it.

Comment: is that my db server fault?

Comment: sir will you help me how to fix that?

Comment: If you using prepared statments the error should go

Comment: okay sir. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell to the query that you are inserting a date and how it is formatted just like this i think:

```
INSERT INTO `amc`(`amc_id`, `amc_type`, `amc_start_date`, `amc_end_date`, `renual_date`, `renual_ammount`, `client_id`, `machine_id`) VALUES ('$amc_id','$amc_type',STR_TO_DATE('$amc_start_date', '%d-%m%y'),STR_TO_DATE('$amc_end_date', '%d-%m%y'),STR_TO_DATE('$amc_renual_date', '%d-%m%y'),'$renual_ammount','$client_id','$machine_id')
```

Comment: thank you sir for your reply i have changed the query as you provided but it saving date as 2020-08-30 only. no other date enter to database

Comment: when you insert date try to insert the str_to_date like this STR_TO_DATE('$amc_end_date', '%Y-%m-%d'), moreover this try to remove the apostrophes when you specify in which table insert data -> INSERT INTO amc[...]